# Strange blank page between abstract and ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, page-breaking, abstract, report

I am puzzled by a blank page appearing between my abstract and ToC. Since I'm using the `report` document class, I am not expecting LaTeX to insert any blank pages. Here is a MWE showing the problem:

```
% Testing behavior of abstract+tableofcontents
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{report}

\title{Project title}

\author{Authors...}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
    This is a dummy abstract...
\end{abstract}

\textsf{\tableofcontents}

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\subsection{Subsection 2}

\section{Section 2}

\chapter{Chapter 2}

\end{document}
```

Any clues as to why the blank page is appearing and how to get rid of it will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Write `{\sffamily\tableofcontents}` instead of `\textsf{\tableofcontents}`.
The `\textsf` is intended for (smaller) texts and will start a paragraph if used in vertical mode (i.e. between paragraphs). Then `\tableofcontents` adds its page break which causes an empty page.